# Match ":" with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Here I want to find a sentence in text that starts with the word **expert** and have **in** until **.** (dot):

```
import re

string = 'We need a person expert in python. also familiar with django.'
pattern = re.finditer(r'(expert)[^.]*\b(in)\b[^.]*[.]', string)
for p in pattern:
    print(p.group(0))
    
# output:expert in python.
```

In addition to the **.** (dot) I want to add **":"** (quotation mark colon quotation mark) as well (I know we can't use () inside [], but only for clarifying the issue):

```
pattern = re.finditer(r'(expert)[^.(":")]*\b(in)\b[^.(":")]*[.(":")]', string)
```

So for `string = We need a person expert in python":" also familiar in django.` `print(p.group(0))` must give `expert in python":"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern to not cross matching `.` or `":"` or `in` until you match `in` first.

Then match until the first occurrence of either `.` or `":"`

```
\bexpert(?:(?!":"|\.|\bin\b).)*\bin\b.*?(?:\.|":")
```

- `\bexpert` A word boundary, match `expert`
- `(?:(?!":"|\.|\bin\b).)*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline asserting what is directly to the right is not `":"` or `.` or the word `in`
- `\bin\b` Match `in` between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `.*?(?:\.|":")` Match as least as possible char until the first occurrence of either `.` or `":"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MA4KpH/1)